# Как удалить/выключить блоки на странице сайта, созданного на битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, cms, битрикс24

Есть сайт: https://e-gifts.by/ На этом сайте есть страница: https://e-gifts.by/info/faq/ На странице, слева есть информация, которую нужно либо удалить, либо скрыть. На скрине я обозначил их красным прямоугольником. Помогите пожалуйста советом, как их удалить, или выключить.
Сайт создан на битриксе. Шаблон Аспро Максимум
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Включаем режим правки ([Как включить режим правки](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1832))
2. Наводим курсор на нужный блок до появления "шестеренки", нажимаем на стрелку рядом с шестеренкой
3. Выбираем опцию отключить компонент[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если данные блоки реализованы без компонента, то можно удалить либо закомментировать данные блоки в коде.

[Включение отключенного компонента](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic85033/)